# I want to make the button text unchanged once it has been changed on a click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was working on my project in which i have grid view of which there is a status field which has button in it .
When user clicks on that button the text of that button gets changed from pending to confirm .
The problem is that when I close the browser and load the .aspx page again through visual studio the text of the button again gets set to pending which i does not want.
Can any one tell me how to keep the button text to confirm only once the button get clicked and also when I click on first row status field button all the rest  status field gets updated with confirm status in database.
Here is my code: (Front End Code)

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="packagename" HeaderText="Package" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="mobileno" HeaderText="Mobile No" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="noofdays" HeaderText="No. of Days" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="child" HeaderText="No. of Children" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="adults" HeaderText="No of Adults" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Field">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MYCOMMAND"
                    Text="Pending" BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

(Back end Code):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "asd", "xxx" };
        GridView1.DataSource = lst;
        this.BindGrid();
    }


}
protected void btnpreviewwebsite_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/index.aspx");
}
protected void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session.Abandon();
    Session.Clear();
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin Panel/LoginForm.aspx");

}
private void BindGrid()
{

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT packagename,name, gender,mobileno,email,noofdays,child,adults FROM enquiry"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{



    if (e.CommandName == "MYCOMMAND")
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        string sql;
        Button Button1 = (Button)e.CommandSource;
        if (Button1 != null)
            Button1.Text = "Confirm";
        sql = "update enquiry set statusfield='" + Button1.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        con.Open();
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Bind function from asp.net so your button text will be taken from DB result. like below.

In aspx page

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand"
    Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Small" GridLines="None">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="enquiryid" HeaderText="Enquiryid" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="packagename" HeaderText="Package" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="gender" HeaderText="Gender" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="mobileno" HeaderText="Mobile No" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="noofdays" HeaderText="No. of Days" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="child" HeaderText="No. of Children" />
        <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="adults" HeaderText="No of Adults" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status Field">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandName="MYCOMMAND"
                    Text='<%# Bind("statusfield")%>' BorderStyle="None" Font-Bold="True" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In .cs file modify your BindGrid method, so that it can return the statusfield column.

```
 private void BindGrid()
{

   using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\PROJECT SEM6\Online Tours and Travels\App_Data\ToursandTravels.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"))
    {

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT enquiryid,packagename,name, gender,mobileno,email,noofdays,child,adults,statusfield FROM enquiry"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                    GridView1.DataBind();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you the button value stays on confirm text even when i reload the page  but the whole table column that is status field is getting changed to confirm can you tell me how to just update a single row ? @Hemant D

Comment: you need to add where condition in your update statement based on your primary key.

Comment: that I know that i need to use where condition in update query but which control do i need to use in  where condition  can u tell? @Hemant D

Comment: What is the primary key for table "enquiry"?